# Schengen visa limitation?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I have business Schengen visa issued by Italian embassy from 15th July to 22 Oct 2019. I am going to Italy for office work and coming back on 10th Aug to India.
Then on 10th Sept I am going to Europe on vacation with my family. I have applied for tourist visa with French embassy for my family members since longest stay will be in Paris. We are planning to visit Paris, Zurich, Venice, Salzburg & Munich. We will come back on 24 Sept to India.

Do I need to apply for another schengen visa or is my multiple entry Schengen visa enough?

Comment: What is the "duration of stay" listed on your visa, and when will you enter the Schengen area (before your return on 10 August)?

Comment: Visiting 5 countries and cities in 15 days? Including travel to/from India you’ve maybe really only got 13 days. IMHO you'll be spending an awful lot of time travelling between destinations on this itinerary, and not really allowing enough time to see each destination.

Answer (score 4):

With a multiple entry Schengen visa the allowed *duration of stay* is the maximum number of calendar days (midnight to midnight) at least partly spent in the Schengen Area.

Your family vacation (10–24 September) will count as 15 days. Add the days for your business trip. If the sum does not exceed the maximum number of days allowed according to your visa title, you are fine. Having used your visa for its original purpose, you are allowed to what is left of its validity for another visit.

Comment: If they arrive on the 10th and leave on the 24th, that counts as 15 days, not 14.

Comment: Yes, it is 15 days. I have now corrected the misstake.